# How to sort angular ngx datatable with specific criteria

Tags: angular, ngx-datatable

I am developing a table view with angular, ngx datatable where I have few columns that can be sorted. For example I have a column called "full prize" which shows addition of two fields which are row.price1 and row.price2. When I click on column name, I want to sort the table according to full prize. But since the full prize value is a calculated one, I cannot achieve it directly.

```
<ngx-datatable-column name="full price" prop="price1">

<ng-template let-row="row" ngx-datatable-cell-template>

{{row.price1+ row.price2}}

</ng-template>

</ngx-datatable-column>
```

Above given is the way to sort  with  price1. But how to sort with full prize?.

Can anyone help on this. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass a custom comparator function for the column https://swimlane.gitbook.io/ngx-datatable/api/column/inputs#comparator

Comment: Thanks. I searched for use-cases with comparator functions for this. Couldn't find good examples in web. If you have/find any examples, could please share?. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

We can sort with specific criteria in following way.

Using a comparator function, we can compare two rows with custom logic.

```
 private compareByPrice(a, b): number {
   var priceA = a['price1'] + a['price2'] ;
   var priceB = b['price1'] + b['price2'] ;

   if (priceA > priceB) {
        return 1;
   }else if (priceA < priceB) {
        return -1;
   }else {
        return 0;
   }
 }
```

Then we can set this function as comparator in html.

```
<ngx-datatable-column prop="" name="Price" [comparator]="compareByPrice">
 <ng-template ngx-datatable-cell-template let-row="row">
  {{row.price1 + row.price2}}
 </ng-template>
</ngx-datatable-column>
```

Note : prop value must be set to "" for preventing default sorting.